# mat-paginator width is not aligned with mat-table

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, material-table

I am using angular material for my table. In my code some time data will exceed monitor size so a horizontal scroll bar will appear. In that case my paginator is not aligned with table as like below

[image]

I want to align both mat-table and mat-paginator with the same width.

Below is my html

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
  
    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
  </div>
```

Below is my CSS

```
table {
    width: 100%;
  }
```

please help me to fix this issue

Comment: Wrap the table with a container with style `overflow:auto`

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure paginator fits into the full width of the parent container. This can be achieved by placing the following CSS class into component style file:

```
.table-container {
  width: fit-content;
}
```

Include this style in the parent container of the table.

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8 table-container">
...
...
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution for me `<div style="display: inline-table;"`

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8 style="display: inline-table;"">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}}</td> 
    </ng-container>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi moio99 m 2 63
Thank you for trying to answer this question. Could you take a look at possibly cleaning your answer up a little bit using the correct code formatting, and perhaps a full example?

Comment: For the proposed case I would have to put this:  <div class="mat-elevation-z8 style="display: inline-block;"">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
    </ng-container>

Comment: I've moved your comment into your answer. Once/if it is approved as an edit, please feel free to make any changes you think are necessary

Comment: Setting `display` property to `inline-table` doesn't appear to work.